# Referencing Two Excel Documents - Determine Value with Multiple Column Inputs

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to simplify this. Let's say I have the below Excel Tables (both are separate files).

Table 1 (csv for reference of columns - file is NOT CSV format though)

```
X52519, description1, vendor, Blue, Hard, Square    
X73849, Description2, vendorTwo, Red, Soft, Round    
X63825, Description3, vendorThree, Red, Hard, Fruit
X49582, Description4, vendorFive, Blue, Hard, Fruit
```

Table 2  (csv style for reference of columns)

```
Blue, Hard, Square, Lego
Blue, Hard, Round, Hula-Hoop
Red, Soft, Round, ball
Red, Hard, Fruit, apple
Orange, Soft, Fruit, Orange
Green, soft, small, Pea
```

I want table 1 to have a formula column on the ends of it and based on the results, show Table 2 Value. In real life, Tables 1 and 2 have many different columns and are more complex, but should be referenced. Table 2 is a master and holds more info such as descriptions, numbers, and such that are irrelevant to this post. I just wanted to explain so it wasn't an obvious solution to just add it to the first Spreadsheet. These two Documents must stay separate.

I want the final results of Table 1 to look like this:
Table 1 (6 Columns)

```
X52519, description1, vendor, Blue, Hard, Square, Lego    
X73849, Description2, vendorTwo, Red, Soft, Round, Ball    
X63825, Description3, vendorThree, Red, Hard, Fruit, Apple
X49582, Description4, vendorFive, Blue, Hard, Fruit, Does Not Exist
```

If a solution is not very easy to describe here, maybe some guidance. Ideally, I would want the Fourth column of Table 1 to auto-populate without doing anything, but a VB Macro would definitely be doable. Should I Import into Microsoft Access and use that? Just looking for some guidance and solutions if anybody has any ideas. I was told VLOOKUP would be very complex.

**EDIT
As I'm reading this I'm finding more misunderstandings (I'm sure all on my part as I am new to the community. The "(If ...)" sections of table 2 were meant for Reference and were not part of the data. I was trying to say if the combination is blah, blah, blah from table 1, column D of table 1 should show apple because the other spreadsheet file says blah blah blah means apple. Does that clarify? I apologize for any confusion. I modified the question to hopefully clarify this better.

Comment: Are you required to keep Table 2 as one column? Is that literally how it looks? If you could get it to be four columns, we could use a multiple criteria Index/Match in Table 1 to get your solution.

Comment: If you have a programming question, please show what you have done and what doesn't work. You can't learn how to program with one question starting from scratch

Comment: I'm not necessarily trying to program, I'm trying to find guidance for best methods. I was testing around with access but am unfamiliar with it so before I take some time to attack that I was looking for insight into what a good approach would be. My starting was simply in SQL which is the language I'm familiar with, but I would hate to have to constantly import data. I thought there must be a simpler excel formula solution. Even just guidance would help.

Comment: @BruceWayne - This question has been edited - your multiple criteria Index/Match solution might now be do-able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your table 1 was on a sheet called `Sheet1` and your table 2 was on a sheet called `Sheet2` and both tables started in cell A1 of their respective sheets, a formula in cell D1 of sheet `Sheet1` that will generate the values you are looking for could be:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,(MATCH($A1&", "&$B1&", "&$C1&")",MID(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,FIND("(If ",Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)+4,999),0))),FIND(" ",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,(MATCH($A1&", "&$B1&", "&$C1&")",MID(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3,FIND("(If ",Sheet2!$A$1:$A$3)+4,999),0))))-1))
```

That formula would need to be entered as a CSE formula (i.e. press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to "enter" the formula), and then it can be copied to cells D2 and D3.

Obviously, the references to sheets could be changed to refer to sheets in whichever workbooks you are using, and the cell references could also be adjusted to suit the location of your data within the sheets.

---

I strongly recommend that you **don't** use the formula (I only created it to prove to myself that I could, because I don't often use `INDEX`, `MATCH`, and especially CSE formulae), but instead think about reformatting your data (if possible) so that it is in a format that is more conducive to easier calculations.

Comment: Woooo that's a nice formula. I had the same kind of idea, glad to see it could work. But I agree with your note at the end. I am thinking to do Text to Columns to break up table 2, and doing a "simple" multi criteria Index/Match. Nicely done!!

Comment: @BruceWayne - "nice" only in the sense of "complicated, esoteric, cryptic, unmaintainable"  :D  But it was a nice challenge for my lunch break to see whether I could do it.

Comment: @BruceWayne - or maybe "nice" = "No. I Can't Explain!!"

Comment: hahaha, I was going to put in quotes "well, to some". I like it though, there's a lot going on in there which helped me learn too. *Thumbs up*

Comment: It is not something that we can just change the organization of, according to others at my company. I will see what I can do, but if it works why not use that formula? Why do you recommend that I don't use it? This is not CSV format. It is actually two complicated excel sheets with formula in them already. One being the master and the other being a subcategory with thousands more parts in it.

Comment: Also, I do want to note that the question wasn't for different sheets, but for different workbook document files in excel. I know I can reference an outside workbook in a separate sheet so is that the solution? Make sheet2 = workbook2 via connection to other sources? Thanks for all the help everyone!

Comment: As I'm reading this I'm finding more misunderstandings (I'm sure all on my part as I am new to the community. The "(If ...)" sections of table 2 were meant for Reference and were not part of the data. I was trying to say if the combination is blah, blah, blah from table 1, column D of table 1 should show apple because the other spreadsheet file says blah blah blah means apple. Does that clarify? I apologize for any confusion

Comment: @SeanDon - I think you will need to format your sample data in the question to show what is in which columns (e.g. it's very hard for us to understand how `X52519, description1, vendor, Blue, Hard, Square` is 3 columns) or, better still, paste screen dumps of the 2 tables (showing column and row numbers) into the question.

Comment: Got it. Sorry. When I updated the question to try to be more clear I missed this section. I will fix this. They are all columns though

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if your Table1 looks like this:

[image]

And then your Table2 looks like this:

[image]

In `G2` in Table1, you can use this array formula (meaning, enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>

`=INDEX(Table2!$D$1:$D$6,MATCH(Table1!D1&Table1!E1&Table1!F1,Table2!$A$1:$A$6&Table2!$B$1:$B$6&Table2!$C$1:$C$6,0))`

and drag down.

The `#N/A` error means that you don't have that combination. You could wrap `IfError()` around the `Index/Match` to return something...say `=IfError([formula above],"No such combination")`.